# Python: How to compare columns with text entries and with each other

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, venn-diagram

I'm a total python noob just started with scripting.
I have a dataframe of three samples and for each sample I have a list of Peptide sequences, like:

```
d = {'Sample 1': ['QSFLEVSYYPMAGYIKEDSIM', 'MLPIQTRIAS', 'AAVACTVLRCLAAEQQTSRSVDEAY'], 'Sample 2': ['QSFLEVSYYPTEIRQMGM', 'AEAARLVLAARIKGDAM', 'AAVACTVLRCLAAEQQTSRSVDEAY'], 'Sample 3': ['AAIGVHLGCTSACVAVYAADRGMKL', 'QSFLEVSYYPTEIRQMGM', 'AAVACTVLRCLAAEQQTSRSVDEAY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What I want to do is find out which of these peptides are mutual in the three samples and plot a venn diagram

I did this with two samples but then I couldn't find much help so I did the venn plotting 'manually'

```
import matplotlib_venn as vplt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_txt = pd.read_csv('all_Peptides_sortFN.txt', delimiter='\t')
df_txt.count()
df_txt['Peptides'] = df_txt["FN"] + df_txt["FN_18"]
AllPeps = df_txt.groupby('Peptides').count()
AllPeps.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)
AllPeps = df_txt.groupby('Peptides').count()
AllPeps.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)
AllPeps['result'] = np.where(AllPeps['FN'] == AllPeps['FN_18'], '1', '0')
AllPeps.head()
AllPeps.result.value_counts()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
v = venn2(subsets=(3411, 1737, 1150), set_labels = ('Filgrastim', 'Filgrastim 18O'))
plt.title('Comparison of peptides in just digested and 18O-labeled Filgrastim(new batch)')
plt.savefig('VennFN.png')
plt.show()
```

I appreciate every suggestion :)

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn3
venn3([set(v) for v in d.values()], set_labels=d.keys())
```